# Passing JSON data in HTML to JSON

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, jsp

From my controller page, I set my JSON to .jsp

```
jsonObject.add("map:", jsonArray);
session.setAttribute("mapJSON", gson.toJson(jsonObject));
```

Right now my .jsp page stores a JSON output from my controller

```
<%=session.getAttribute("mapJSON")%>
```

From the same .jsp page, I got a script tag below trying to get the JSON data and generate some result

```
var colors = ['rgb(240,249,232)', 'rgb(204,235,197)', 'rgb(168,221,181)', 'rgb(123,204,196)', 'rgb(78,179,211)', 'rgb(43,140,190)', 'rgb(8,88,158)'];
var data = {};
var mapJSON = <%=session.getAttribute("mapJSON")%>;

$(document).on('click', '#map-btn', function (event) {
    $('#place').html('-');
    $('#interest-point').html('-');


    $.getJSON(mapJSON , function (results) {
        results.map.forEach(function (area, i) {
            var id = area['place'];
            var population = area['interest-point'];

            data[id] = area;

            $('#' + id).css('fill', colors[population]);
        });
    });
});
```

Are they any ways that I could access my JSON data from jQuery?

Comment: what do you mean by **Are they any ways that I could access my JSON data from jQuery?** you are already showing jquery codes

Comment: It seems like mapJSON would be a javascript object containing your data, so there is no need to use $.getJSON to do an ajax request to retrieve that same data.  You could probably run the inner forEach func direcly on mapJSON or possibly mapJSON.map, depending on what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can read **mapJSON** as String field and use JSON library for converting:

1. String to JSON
2. JSON to string in jQuery

Example Library:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse